# ActionBar with NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

When I click one of tabs, I just want to show a dialogue on top of current view without switching the tab.

I could achieve this behavior by overriding onTabChanged when I used TabHost and TabSpec.
But now I switched to using actionbar's tab, and having hard time finding the solution.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to switch the current tab? Why not use buttons instead?

Comment: I have 5 tabs and I want to treat one of the tabs as a button.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this sounds counter-intuitive. Your users most likely will be confused.

Comment: @WolframRittmeyer: I'll modify my design. Thanks